# SpecFlow - API same scenario in different environment using runsettings using rest

Tags: restsharp, specflow, runsettings

Apologies, if this has already been asked, but please bare with me, i am new to restSharp and API testing. I have ready many posts,articles and responses. But due to my limitation, I was wondering if anyone can just guide me through, on how to achieve it.

What i would like to achieve, is to run the same test scenario in different test environments(dev, uat, pro etc..) for the same Gherkin scenarios, if possible by making use of the tags e.g @dev @uat etc..

Currently, we have 3 runsetting files for each of these environments, (dev.runsetting, uat.runsetting etc..in each we pass different parameters), to change to different environment, i do this through C# and select the necessary test setting files

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to control via tags which scenario is executed against which environment.

The SpecFlow+ Runner has a feature called `Targets` that could help you. With this, you can define multiple targets and their configuration, for your scenarios.

You can find an example for this feature here: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest

In this example, we are using the targets to test against different browsers.
In your case, I would change the browser to your environments.

In your CI/CD pipeline, you could then use the filtering in the SpecFlow+ Runner to filter out for your different environments. In Azure DevOps the filter criteria is `Name~\(target: <TARGETNAME>\)`.

Documentation for it is here: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-runner/en/latest/Profile/Filter.html

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the maintainers and developers on SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: apologies to ask these questions, but do i need to create a default.srprofile file which will includes the target environments? Also, do how i call specific environment runsetting files? say, i already have dev.runsetting file which includes other environment specific information. How will Specflow make a call to this file? in the  Target Value section, do i need to put the path were this file resided?  apologies for asking too many questions.

Comment: You need to create the default.srProfile in your project. I would put your environment specific information also in there. As Environment Variable or in a Config file. Depends on your project setup. You should not need the runsettings file than anymore, so no need to access them.

Comment: thank you for the reply, is it not possible to call another file from the default.srProfile file? The reason i ask this question, is that in the dev.runsetting we have more parameter, were we pass specific data for the environment, like user id , tokens etc